# How to import python module?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I want to install a library that will allow me to use units of measure (for example: Lumen, etc.).
I installed a package on the computer (through the cmd), the package I see in the environment settings work at Visual Studio but I can not import it into the project and use it.
I added a screenshot to illustrate.

[image]

Comment: Your package installation seems to have failed according to the error messages in the bottom left corner of your screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in your own screenshot (in the lower left), your installation of `python-units` seems to have failed:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-units==0.1.2 (from version: none)
```

Furthermore:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-units==0.1.2
```

Noting that you appear to be using Python 3.7 (again, from your screenshot) and checking the [file download page for python-units on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-units/#files), we can see that only Python 2.x is supported (as indicated in the only available `.whl` filename):

```
python_units-0.1.2-py2-none-any.whl
```